# JSON to CSV via FasterCSV

Tags: ruby, json, fastercsv

I'm new to Ruby and had a question. I'm trying to create a .rb file that converts JSON to CSV.

I came across some disparate sources that got me to make:

```
require "rubygems"
require 'fastercsv'
require 'json'

csv_string = FasterCSV.generate({}) do |csv|
   JSON.parse(File.open("small.json").read).each do |hash|
    csv << hash
  end
end

puts csv_string
```

Now, it does in fact output text but they are all squashed together without spaces, commas etc. How do I make it more customised, clear for a CSV file so I can export that file?

The JSON would look like:

```
        {
            "results": [
                {
                    "reportingId": "s", 
                    "listingType": "Business", 
                    "hasExposureProducts": false, 
                    "name": "Medeco Medical Centre World Square", 
                    "primaryAddress": {
                        "geoCodeGranularity": "PROPERTY", 
                        "addressLine": "Shop 9.01 World Sq Shopng Cntr 644 George St", 
                        "longitude": "151.206172", 
                        "suburb": "Sydney", 
                        "state": "NSW", 
                        "postcode": "2000", 
                        "latitude": "-33.876416", 
                        "type": "VANITY"
                    }, 

                    "primaryContacts": [
                        {
                            "type": "PHONE", 
                            "value": "(02) 9264 8500"
                        }
                    ]
                },xxx
        }
```

The CSV to just have something like:

```
        reportingId, s, listingType, Business, name, Medeco Medical...., addressLine, xxxxx, longitude, xxxx, latitude, xxxx, state, NSW, postcode, 2000, type, phone, value, (02) 92648544
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like? What do you want the CSV to look like?

Comment: just updated question mate. Ta

Comment: That's a weird CSV format - normally CSV would have keys columns in the first row and values as columns in later rows (hence mapping your nested JSON structure is going to be messy)

Comment: That's fine. i am not fussy with CSV format, just something that is exportable to excel. Yeah JSon is nested and a bit complicated, so whether its easier to take everything or selectively is fine with me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your JSON structure is a mix of hashes and lists, and also has levels of different heights, it is not as trivial as the code you show. However (assuming your input files always look the same) it shouldn't be hard to write an appropriate converter. On the lowest level, you can transform a hash to CSV by

```
hash.to_a.flatten
```

E.g.

```
input = JSON.parse(File.open("small_file.json").read)
writer = FasterCSV.open("out.csv", "w")
writer << input["results"][0]["primaryAddress"].to_a.flatten
```

will give you

```
type,VANITY,latitude,-33.876416,postcode,2000,state,NSW,suburb,Sydney,longitude,151.206172,addressLine,Shop 9.01 World Sq Shopng Cntr 644 George St,geoCodeGranularity,PROPERTY
```

Hope that guides you the direction.

Btw, your JSON looks invalid. You should change the `},xxx` line to `}]`.

Comment: Thanks yeah i know its invalid but its something that comes from a server out of my control, but i should look at doing my own one that way. THanks for that

Comment: Only issue i am having is there isnt a space between the value then the next key... based on what i have, how do u add that extra space?